# error: unfortunately app stopped working

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I am working on an android project where the app is supposed to invoke the video recording interface, allow the user to record the video, and then go back to the activity to process the video.
I used intents for this purpose, the code does not have any errors and works fine until I finish recording the video and press "ok" to return to the main activity or cancel to cancel the recording. when the user presses either ok or cancel and before the focus goes back to the app it stops working with the message "unfortunately, appName has stopped working"
I tried so hard to find the error in my code but I couldn't
I think it is the "onActvityResult" method. because when the execution reaches it the app stops.
as a beginner could anyone please help
thank you so much
this is my code until now

```
package com.example.myproject.vlc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);}

//----------------------------------------------------------
    //Button btnReadyToGo= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReady);

    public void onButtonClick(View view1){   //if button is clicked
    //TextView label3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl3);
    //label3.setTextColor(Color.CYAN); //change color
        //----------------------------invoke the video recording built in      interface-----------------------------------------------------------

        String CAPTURE_TITLE="MyVideo.3gp";

        File myfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     "/DCIM/", CAPTURE_TITLE);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( myfile );
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent2.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
        //----------------------------------------------



        //----------------------------------------------
} //end of OnButtonclick funciton

//----------------------------------------------------------------
 // private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
final static int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED = 1;
// Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
// startActivityForResult(intent1, VIDEO_CAPTURE);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------


//---------------------------------after recording finishes--------------------------------
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri uri2=data.getData();
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" + uri2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, uri2.getPath() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    //------------------------getting video length-------------------------------------
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/"+ "MyVideo.3gp");
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
    long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is my logcat:

```
    11-20 06:17:30.094    1600-1600/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
     11-20 06:17:30.158    1600-1600/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class     referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14055: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14059: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-20 06:17:30.162    1600-1600/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 401: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 423: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-20 06:17:30.174    1600-1600/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-20 06:17:30.690    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
11-20 06:17:30.694    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8caf700, tid 1600
11-20 06:17:30.714    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
11-20 06:17:30.714    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-20 06:17:30.894    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-20 06:17:30.898    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
11-20 06:17:30.898    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
11-20 06:17:30.974    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
11-20 06:17:30.974    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
11-20 06:17:30.974    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-20 06:17:53.886    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-20 06:17:53.886    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cfab20)
11-20 06:17:53.886    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.israajaradat.vlc, PID: 1600
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.israajaradat.vlc/com.example.israajaradat.vlc.Activity1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.israajaradat.vlc.Activity1.onActivityResult(Activity1.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 06:17:53.894    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 11% free 3777K/4208K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
11-20 06:17:55.690    1600-1600/com.example.israajaradat.vlc I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1600 SIG: 9
```

Comment: and where's the logcat?

Comment: logcat attached to the post ... thanks @FrankN.Stein